# Kotlin ternary operator

Tags: android, kotlin, syntax, equivalent

How can I convert the following code from Java to Kotlin?

```
Boolean mBoolean = false
view.setVisibility(mBoolean ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Comment: Android Studio can convert the code for you. If the problem you have is with the ternary expression, then the equivalent construct in kotlin is `if else`.

Comment: It is possible to use the `when` expression too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
val mBoolean = false
view.visibility = if(mBoolean) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

However I doubt it makes any sense to make `mBoolean` immutable here, so instead of `val mBoolean` I'd go with `var mBoolean`.

Comment: `var` would be the correct translation since `mBoolean` isn't `final` in the Java code.

Comment: It is always better to use `val` in Kotlin. For example, there are some features, like smart cases that would work with `val` and not with `var` declarations

Answer (score 0):

You can epannd on `view.visibility = if(mBoolean) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE` by creating extension function

```
fun View.makeVisible(show:Boolean){
    this.visibilility = if(show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE   
}


var mBolean = false
view.makeVisible(mBoolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **when** operator:

```kotlin
 val mBoolean = false
        view.visibility = when (mBoolean) {
            true -> View.VISIBLE
            false -> View.GONE
        }
```